# How to create constructor with empty ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

I wrote a constructors that can passes all the fields, including an Arraylist. I don't know what to do if I want constructors where I'm not passing the Arraylist and instead give it an empty Arraylist.

For example I already wrote a Course class and now I'm writing a Student class. The student class contains an Arraylist.

```
class Student {
    String studentFirstName;
    String studentLastName;
    ArrayList<Course> studentSchedule = new ArrayList<Course>();

    // Constructors
    Student(String newFirstName,  String newLastName) {
        this.Student(newFirstName, newLastName, _______ ); //what to put in the blank?
    }

    Student(String newFirstName, String newLastName, ArrayList<Course> newSchedule) {
        this.studentFirstName = newFirstName;
        this.studentLastName = newLastName;
        this.studentSchedule = newSchedule;
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

I'm stuck here. Putting null in the blank does not work, I get compiler warning: The method Student(String, String, null) is undefined for the type Student Obviously I'm missing the point.

How do I get the constructor to give me an empty Arraylist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you want to pass an empty ArrayList, so pass an empty ArrayList:

```
class Student {
    String studentFirstName;
    String studentLastName;
    List<Course> studentSchedule; // no initialization here: it's done in the constructor

    // Constructors
    Student(String newFirstName,  String newLastName) {
        this(newFirstName, newLastName, new ArrayList<Course>());
    }

    Student(String newFirstName, String newLastName, List<Course> newSchedule) {
        this.studentFirstName = newFirstName;
        this.studentLastName = newLastName;
        this.studentSchedule = newSchedule;
    }
```

Note that you should generally declare the field as `List<Course>`, not as `ArrayList<Course>`, unless it's really important for the list to be an ArrayList, and not any other kind of list. Program on interfaces.

Also, your fields should be private, and shouldn't be named studentXxx. They're part of the Student class, so it's redundant. `lastName` is sufficient, and more redable.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `List` interface and best naming practices. One could additionally consider a defensive copy like `this.studentSchedule = new ArrayList<Course>(newSchedule);` to prevent the list from being modified after it has been passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

To pass an empty `ArrayList`:

```
this(newFirstName, newLastName, new ArrayList<Course>());
```

(Also note that the correct syntax is `this.`, not `this.Student.`)

Answer (score 0):

Probably passing new empty instance of `Arraylist` is your question if I got it correct

```
this (newFirstName, newLastName, new ArrayList<Course>())
```

Or, you can pass `null` also,

```
this (newFirstName, newLastName, null)
```

**Edit :**

After @Erwin's comment, to invoke constructor of same class, you should use `this()` only.

Comment: 'this.Student(' does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Just construct an empty `ArrayList` and pass it to the constructor:

```
Student(String newFirstName,  String newLastName) {
    this(newFirstName, newLastName, new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Also, notice that I've used `this()` to call `Student`'s other constructor, as opposed to `this.Student()` which is invalid.

Notice, though, that you are already initializing the `ArrayList` field at the point of declaration. You should consider removing this initialization if you want it to take place via the constructor.